# How can I reuse the same steps and defaults across different jobs in a callable Github Actions workflow?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have three different jobs in a callable workflow that are pretty much identical except for the very last step. Right now I have a workflow that works perfectly but looks really ugly as there is so much repeated code:

```
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      working-directory:
        required: true
        type: string
jobs:
  lint:
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ${{inputs.working-directory}}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18.x
          cache: "npm"
          cache-dependency-path: "${{inputs.working-directory}}/package-lock.json"
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run lint
  typecheck:
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ${{inputs.working-directory}}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18.x
          cache: "npm"
          cache-dependency-path: "${{inputs.working-directory}}/package-lock.json"
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run typecheck
  test:
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ${{inputs.working-directory}}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18.x
          cache: "npm"
          cache-dependency-path: "${{inputs.working-directory}}/package-lock.json"
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run test --if-present
```

I've tried to make the defaults shareable across jobs and made a setup job that is needed by the three jobs:

```
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      working-directory:
        required: true
        type: string
defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: ${{inputs.working-directory}}
jobs:
  setup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18.x
          cache: "npm"
          cache-dependency-path: "${{inputs.working-directory}}/package-lock.json"
      - run: npm ci
  lint:
    needs: setup
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: npm run lint
  typecheck:
    needs: setup
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: npm run typecheck
  test:
    needs: setup
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: npm run test --if-present
```

However, this gives me the error:

> Unrecognized named-value: 'inputs'. Located at position 1 within expression: inputs.working-directory

How to make the workflow work with as much code reuse as possible?

Comment: You can try [reusing workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows). With this you can avoid copy pasting the same workflow over and over.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work because you will get a clean agent for each of your job.

So even you defined this in that way

```
lint:
    needs: setup
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: npm run lint
```

The agent for the ling job will not get result of the setup job. It will just run after it.

If you want to reduce here repeatable code you need to use [composite actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action) or [reusable workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows).

With composite action it may look like:

- composite actions

```
name: 'NPM shared steps'
description: 'NPM shared steps'
inputs:
working-directory:
  description: 'Wowrking directory'
  required: true
runs:
using: "composite"
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - name: Use Node.js
    uses: actions/setup-node@v3
    with:
      node-version: 18.x
      cache: "npm"
      cache-dependency-path: "${{inputs.working-directory}}/package-lock.json"
  - run: npm ci
```

- and then

```
on:
 workflow_call:
   inputs:
     working-directory:
       required: true
       type: string
defaults:
 run:
   working-directory: ${{inputs.working-directory}}
jobs:
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   steps:
     - id: run-shared-npm
       uses: actions/npm-shared-steps-action@v1
       with:
         working-directory: '${{inputs.working-directory}}'
     - run: npm run lint
 typecheck:
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   steps:
     - id: run-shared-npm
       uses: actions/npm-shared-steps-action@v1
       with:
         working-directory: '${{inputs.working-directory}}'
     - run: npm run typecheck
 test:
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   steps:
     - id: run-shared-npm
       uses: actions/npm-shared-steps-action@v1
       with:
         working-directory: '${{inputs.working-directory}}'
     - run: npm run test --if-present
```